# Creating nurbs curves using python

Tags: maya, python

I'm trying to automate the creation of nurbs curves using python for an auto rigger I am making. Unfortunately I cant seem to wrap my head around the cmds.curve command making the curve periodic. This script is supposed to take a given curve, get the coordinates of each CV and then using the curve command should create a new identical curve. This works fine until I try and make the curve periodic, and it seems to give me a Maya Command error on the cmds.curve line. I'm not sure what the issue is or how the knots flag works.

```
#get curve's CVs

cvs = cmds.ls('{}.cv[*]'.format('CTRL'),fl=1)

points = []



#get coordinates of each cv

for cv in cvs:

loc = cmds.xform(cv, q=1, t=1)

points.append(loc)

#create the knots list starting from -2

knotsList = list(range(len(points)+2))

knotsList = [x-2.0 for x in knotsList]



#create the curve

cmds.curve(n='CTRL', d=3, per=True, p=points, k=knotsList)
```

Comment: periodic curves have less knots as the first ones are the last ones. so no +2

Comment: When I remove the +2 I get the error: RuntimeError: Knot vector is too short.  Must have length (#CVs + degree - 1) #

Comment: yeah well been a while since i used maya and mel daily (about 6years). alternative is to just make it open and close it as a separate command

Comment: Thanks that works, I'll probably end up using but it there's part of me that really wants to understand why and how the command works so I'm gonna keep researching